# How do I send Video data into Kinesis Video Stream?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

I have been reading the Kinesis Video Stream [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/KinesisVideo.html) (Javascript) for a few days now I can't figure out how to send my video? I also read the [Kinesis](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Kinesis.html) documentation plus [firehose](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Firehose.html), but no luck.

I have already created the stream with [`createStream()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/KinesisVideo.html#createStream-property) API.

#### Param:

```
var params = {
    APIName: "PUT_MEDIA",
    StreamName: streamName
};
```

#### getDataEndpoint():

In order to write data.

```
kinesisVideo.getDataEndpoint(params,function(err,data){
    if(err)
      console.log(err,err.stack);
    else{
      console.log(data);
      // How to Send DATA?
    }
});
```

Comment: Normally you would use one of the producer SDKs but there is no JavaScript producer SDK afaik. Perhaps you could write this one component of your app in one of the supported languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the [GStreamer plugin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/gs-send-data.html)

Alternatively you can use the [producer SDKS for Java, Android, or C++](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/producer-sdk.html)

Comment: Gstreamer is a command line application. You would send the stream directly from your webcam, but you don't control it from the browser. If you want to capture the camera directly from the browser, you need to do some preprocessing. You basically can capture the frames from the webcam, send them over to a lambda function, and that function can convert to a MKV file that can be sent over to Kinesis video streams. There is a nice demo of that at https://github.com/brain-power/Brain-Power-Amazon-Fidgetology

Comment: So I just use the endpoint to send my video through GStreamer?

Comment: You compile the GStreamer demo as it says at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/gs-send-data.html, then you start it passing the parameters for your stream, your region, and your secret key. You have more details about the plugin at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/examples-gstreamer-plugin.html

Comment: Thank you, I can understand much better now.